# Does storing Faceook's social graph in our database violate the terms of service?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

We are creating an application that will ask the user for permission to their friends, and then will store their friends_ids in our database, does this violate the terms of service?  If so, where can we find this violation cause I couldnt seem to find it.

Comment: Realistically only your company's lawyers can answer this, though i guess other people here can give you their interpretation, i'd be wary of acting on any advice you get from non-lawyers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Platform Policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/), section II.

You can store the data, but be sure to make it clear to the user. You can't use the data outside of the application or sell it (obviously). For friends list, you should update the list every 24 hours to account for new / removed friends.